# Redux - npm run dev

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

After executing the command

```
npm i --save-dev react-redux@5.0.2 redux@3.6.0
```

and then

```
npm run dev
```

is showing the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCFCa.jpg)

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: you don't have a script called `dev` in `package.json`.

Comment: Please add the error, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

`--save-dev` Is to save a dependancy as a devDependancy.

Which doesn't mean that you can do `npm run dev`

You need to modify your `package.json` file

```
 "scripts": {
  "dev": "xxxx"
}
```